# Нужны ли запятые после подчинительных союзов?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

1.1. Где деньги, которые(,) ты сказала, Женя мне переведёт?

1.2. Где деньги, которые(,) ты сказала, что Женя мне переведёт?

2.1. Это то, что(,) я думал, он спрятал.

2.2. Это то, что(,) я думал, что он спрятал.

Comment: Первая фраза грамматически должна быть записана так: где "деньги", которые ты сказала,(что) Женя мне должен? Потому что ты сказала: "деньги". Но это больше разговорный вариант, а правильный вариант формулировки, должен звучать: где деньги, про которые ты рассказывала,.. . Так что не хватает предлога, и форма слова другая.

Comment: 2-ое предложение, мэтр Лео-тык, вводный оборот звучит "я думаю" или "как я думал", вариант "я думал" - ни туда ни сюда, тоже какая-то разговорная форма. В разговорной форме нельзя однозначно определить интонацию, либо она определяется синтаксисом.

Comment: Вы мне не нравитесь, Буратино.

Comment: Почему? и в чём это выражается?)

Comment: Вы толком ничего-с не делаете – только что-то тявкаете в комментариях, не помогая-таки, и про неграмотность высказываний иногда говорите.

Comment: Ну так вы ничего не мяукаете в ответ, как мне понять, помогаю я или нет, я же не ванга-кот-мэтр. Про неграмотность говорю, потому что грамотность для меня нечто большее чем правильность синтаксиса и орфография. Грамотность для меня прежде всего мысль содержащаяся и её обработка, а если мысли нет, я называю такой набор букв не грамотным - я не прав? Я делаю ровно с тем толком, какой заложен в вашем вопросе, вы-с мэтр-босс-сэр. Я даже больше скажу-с, я отражаю только ту игру, какую вы задаете-с, это моё таки совойство.

Comment: @Буратино Тогда почему Вы в первом комментарии не ставите кавычки, к тому же разделяя на пустом месте подлежащее и сказуемое?

Comment: @Максим где конкретно? будем считать, я нервничаю и ставлю лишние знаки и не ставлю нужные кавычки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом и третьем случаях запятые нужны:

***Где деньги, которые, ты сказала, Женя мне переведёт?***;

***Это то, что, я думал, он спрятал***.

Здесь вводные предложения можно опустить без потери структуры.

А в остальных случаях не нужно ставить запятые:

***Где деньги, про которые ты сказала, что Женя мне переведёт? (Добавлен предлог ПРО, иначе будет выглядеть некорректно)***;

***Это то, что я думал, что он спрятал***.

Здесь запятые не нужны (следовательно, это не вводные предложения, а уже **грамматические основы**), т. к., если опустить эти слова, структура потеряется:

*Это то, **что, что** он спрятал*;

*Где деньги, **которые, что** Женя мне переведёт?*;

*Где деньги, **про которые, что** Женя мне переведёт?*

Некорректно по структуре, поэтому запятую **опустить** **нужно**.

Comment: Может, лучше с казать, что запись  (2) и (4) некорректна.  ЧТО – лишний союз.

Comment: @Sharon, так я и писал, что эти записи некорректны. А разве нужны скобки? По-моему, скобки не нужны

Comment: Если из 2-го и 4-го предложений убрать ЧТО,  это будет повтор 1-го и 3-го предложений. Поэтому можно записать только два правильных предложения, а остальные просто  убрать.

Comment: Не, остальные два предложения в моëм ответе тоже я сделал корректными. Просто одни с союзным словом, другие — без. Автор вопроса же два варианта одного предложения писал — вот я и решил из каждого сделать грамматически верное.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.